# How to quickly switch power to a LED strip?

Tags: led, transistors, switching, led-driver

I need to switch a three sets 8 LEDs (1.2V each) in series with a current limiting resistor (~100mA) powered from 15V in under 500ns, about 2000 times per second, separately. The signal will be 3.3V, and at most 20mA.
I considered using a MOSFETs with a driver but that seems really overcomplicated. What would be the best solution?

Comment: MOSFET's are the way to do this. Is each set of LED's taking 100mA? Are all 3 chains on or off at the same time?

Comment: I need to control them independently, there will be a short overlap in ON times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A N channel MOSFET is the obvious way to do this.  Calling this "complicated" makes no sense.  Tie the source to ground, and the LED strip between the 15 V supply and the drain.  With the right kind of MOSFET, a 3.3 V digital signal on the gate can now switch the LED strip on and off.

A candidate FET for this is the IRMLM2502.

Comment: Would SI1480DH also be OK?

Answer (score 0):

8 LEDs in series with Vf drops of of 1.2 volts for each LED, with 100 milliamperes through the string, amounts to 9.6 volts across each string, and since the supply is sitting at 15 volts, the ballast resistor should have a value of:

$$ Rs = \frac{Vs-{n Vf}}{Iled} = \frac{15V- (8\times 1.2V)} {0.1A } = 54 \text { ohms,} $$

and it'll dissipate about 540 milliwatts when it's working.

Comment: Pretty much the only other alternative is adding yet another voltage line. 0,54W for ~12% time is not THAT bad.